# Meaning of "get you programming right from the start"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encoutered the following sentence while reading a computer language book and just wondered the exact meaning of the following sentence (because I'm not a English native speaker):

This book starts with an introductory chapter that covers just enough material to get you *programming right from the start*.

Does "programming right from the start" mean 1) programming correctly, from the start or 2) programming, just from the start?

Comment: ***right** from the start* is a very well-established ***intensified*** collocation *(from the **very** beginning)*, so it's extremely unlikely a native speaker would use that form of words if he specifically intended the sense of *[doing something] **correctly** from the start*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be read in both ways, but my initial and preferred reading is

> to get you programming (right from the start)

with "right" just acting as an intensifier, meaning "from the very start". It means that you will be able to write simple programs immediately.

Comment: I agree. I don't think "programming right" would be a common combination of verb and adverb - it isn't very clear what it means, and "programming correctly" or "programming well" would be more formal and better suited for an instructional book. So "right from the start" makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped.